# EXC_BREAKPOINT CODE=1 Runtime Exception

Tags: swift, exception, breakpoints, runtimeexception

For some odd reason, I am getting the "EXC_BREAKPOINT CODE=1" runtime exception whenever I run this code:

```
var positionX: CGFloat = CGFloat(UInt32(width) + arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width - 2.0 * width)))
```

Can someone tell me why this is? I am at a loss with how to fix this.

Comment: Are you only getting this crash on a 32 bit device, by chance?

Comment: It's running on an iPhone 5s 64 bit, if I run it on a 32bit device I get a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be `self.frame.width` - `width` could be a negative number which will try to cast to `UInt32` which will break.  You may want to debug those 2 values and check before force casting to `UInt32`.  There could also be a problem with whatever property/parameter is applied to the result of this formula.

Also, if just width was a negative number the `UInt32(width)` would fail as well.